# Making a OP code App

Tags: android

i am new to Android App development . i am making an android app for me and my friends which gives the Opcode(Operation Code) for the 8085 microprocessor , user input Assembly instruction . Now the problem is there are around 246 Opcode for different assembly code . I can easily use

```
Switch()
```

statement to find the opcode , but writing 246 cases is repetitive and time consuming . Is there any other easier way to make this app ?

Thanks

Comment: Where the codes will come from? A database? Will you hardcode them into the app?

Comment: I have a pdf like this that i want to use - http://home.iitk.ac.in/~ajalan/opcodes-table-of-intel-8085.pdf

Comment: Reading pdfs is problematic  copy it by hand and save as a csv or plain text then you can go thought is  line by line

Answer (score 0):

Write a script which generates your code

First  create one element by hand  then  take this code  and a file / database which contain the information and for each element generate the code

I would suggest to use the jcodemodel library